# Git commit fails due to insufficient permissions

Tags: git

I am getting the following error while trying to commit to a local repository:

```
error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database .git/objects
```

I created another repository to compare the permissions of `.git` and `.git/objects` and everything works fine in the new repository, and the permissions are the same `drwxr-xr-x`.

What might be causing this error?

Comment: Did you check that the owners and groups are also the same?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can't add file to git repository but can change / commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864872/cant-add-file-to-git-repository-but-can-change-commit)

Comment: If you are on a linux box you can run `strace -f` to inspect which syscall failed.

Answer (score 13):

```
cd repository
chown -R user:group *
cd .git
chown -R user:group *
cd ..
```

the second chown is there because the first one didn't get into .git

Edit: If above does not help, try to run the chown commands as root.

Edit 2: replace 'user' and 'group' with your username and groupname.

Comment: @K.Sopheak maybe you have another problem with permissions. Try running chmod -R u+rwX .git to fix file permissions too.

Comment: Note: you'll want to replace `user` and `group` with your username (or another user/group of your choice). Not sure if this is obvious but it tripped me up

Answer (score 4):

```
cd <path-to-repo>
cd .git/objects
sudo chown -R <username>:<group> *
```

This worked for me with group `staff`.

Comment: Do you have a reason to believe the error is caused by wrong ownership?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue. I thought my current working local repository got corrupted. So I have cloned the repository from remote again. Now I'm able to do commit and push from this new repository without any issues.

Note: If you want your old repo changes then use git stash and do git stash apply in new repo.