# can't add file to git repository but can change / commit

Tags: linux, git

here is error :

```
git add .emacs
error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database .git/objects

error: .emacs: failed to insert into database
error: unable to index file .emacs
fatal: adding files failed
```

how can I fix it ? what's wrong with it ?

Comment: Checkout the permissions on .git and .git/objects, do they make sense?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database .git/objects
```

That is your problem. For some reason or another, Git is having trouble writing to `.git/objects` - typically this means it is owned by another user and doesn't have the proper permissions.

Try seeing what permissions the folder currently has by running `ls -l .git/objects`. Then, you can `chmod` or `chown` (or both) as necessary.

Answer (score 6):

I hadn't changed any permissions on my files, but I had the same error message and fixed it by changing ownership on the git directory (chown -R user:group .git).

Answer (score 4):

This can be caused by accidentally sudo'ing a git commit. You don't intentionally change permissions and sudo will work in most configs, but the next time it is tried without sudo you'll have issues.

Simply revert the permissions on the .git directory to what they would have been previously using a command like this.

```
sudo chown -R user:group .git
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that with more recent (2014+) versions of Git, "[`git commit`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/2c428e4205a50cee19669d5b73cc149ec2254a5d/Documentation/git-commit.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit))</sup> gave *duplicated* error message when the object store was unwritable, which has been corrected with Git 2.34 (Q4 2021).

See [commit 4ef91a2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4ef91a2d795c424eda2bec1bfbbd0c813bcc978a), [commit 119b26d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/119b26d6b9a98fd22bbd340da39cf15d4712fb97) (12 Oct 2021) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 2c428e4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2c428e4205a50cee19669d5b73cc149ec2254a5d), 25 Oct 2021)</sup>

> ### [`commit`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4ef91a2d795c424eda2bec1bfbbd0c813bcc978a): fix duplication regression in permission error output
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>

> Fix a regression in the error output emitted when `.git/objects` can't be written to.
> Before [9c4d6c0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9c4d6c0297b7d6167bf330853139b0515b351b89) ("`cache-tree`: Write updated cache-tree after commit", 2014-07-13, Git v2.2.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3fd13cbcd58f078476cabab926931a3d5bdedfe2)) we'd emit only one "insufficient permission" error, now we'll do so again.
>
> The cause is rather straightforward, we've got `WRITE_TREE_SILENT` for the use-case of wanting to prepare an index silently, quieting any permission etc.
> error output.
> Then when we attempt to update to that (possibly broken) index we'll run into the same errors again.
>
> But with [9c4d6c0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9c4d6c0297b7d6167bf330853139b0515b351b89) the gap between the cache-tree API and the object store wasn't closed in terms of asking `write_object_file()` to be silent.
> I.e.
> post-[9c4d6c0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9c4d6c0297b7d6167bf330853139b0515b351b89) the first call is to `prepare_index()`, and after that we'll call `prepare_to_commit()`.
> We only want verbose error output from the latter.
>
> So let's add and use that facility with a corresponding `HASH_SILENT` flag, its only user is [`cache-tree.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4ef91a2d795c424eda2bec1bfbbd0c813bcc978a/cache-tree.c)'s `update_one()`, which will set it if its `"WRITE_TREE_SILENT"` flag is set.

So in addition of the `chown` you need for fixing the issue, don't be surprise if you see the error message *twice*.

---

You also have a similar error on merges (which does involve `add`)

In read-only repositories, "[`git merge-tree`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/19118cb8570e499e1a56e81740cee3d1c1206b44/Documentation/git-merge-tree.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt-tree))</sup> tried to come up with a merge result tree object, which it failed (which is not wrong) and led to a segfault (which is bad), which has been corrected with Git 2.39 (Q4 2022).

See [commit 92481d1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/92481d1b26ab57525f5efe01d01c7a3d337b8df7), [commit 0b55d93](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0b55d930a69692c7f4e7b90e35fa41f6c46df4bc) (28 Sep 2022) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 19118cb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/19118cb8570e499e1a56e81740cee3d1c1206b44), 10 Oct 2022)</sup>

> ### [`merge-ort`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/92481d1b26ab57525f5efe01d01c7a3d337b8df7): return early when failing to write a blob
>
> <sup>Reviewed-by: Elijah Newren</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>

> In the previous commit, we fixed a segmentation fault when a tree object could not be written.
>
> However, before the tree object is written, `merge-ort` wants to write out a blob object (except in cases where the merge results in a blob that already exists in the database).
> And this can fail, too, but we ignore that write failure so far.
>
> Let's pay close attention and error out early if the blob could not be written.
> This reduces the error output of t4301.25 ("merge-ort fails gracefully in a read-only repository") from:
>
> ```
> error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database ./objects
> error: error: Unable to add numbers to database
> error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database ./objects
> error: error: Unable to add greeting to database
> error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database ./objects
> fatal: failure to merge
> ```
>
> to:
>
> ```
> error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database ./objects
> error: error: Unable to add numbers to database
> fatal: failure to merge
> ```
>
> This is *not* just a cosmetic change: Even though one might assume that the operation would have failed anyway at the point when the new tree object is written (and the corresponding tree object *will* be new if it contains a blob that is new), but that is not so:
>
> As pointed out by Elijah Newren, when Git has previously been allowed to add loose objects via `sudo` calls, it is very possible that the blob object cannot be written (because the corresponding `.git/objects/??/` directory may be owned by `root`) but the tree object can be written (because the corresponding objects directory is owned by the current user).
>
> This would result in a corrupt repository because it is missing the blob object, and with this here patch we prevent that.